# 7E1 to 8N1.........Parity Bit doubts

Tags: parity

I am having doubts in the relation between 7E1 and 8N1. Assuming I am transmitting a sent of characters between a client and a server; client sending with 7 bits and 1 even parity bit (7E1) and the server is to reply the same information switching to 8bits with no parity bit(8N1), how does the conversion happen. I have an example, but I cant seem to understand how the conversion happened. Here is the example
I am transmitting from the client :**"06H 02H 05H 02H 0DH OAH"**(7E1)
The server replies :**"06H B2H 35H B2H 8DH 0AH"**(8N1).

How was the server able to reply with such characters in 8N1 from 7E1 which it received.

Thanks.

Comment: The parity mode has to be same at both ends of the channel (ie server and client) to make any meaningful interpretation of the data.

Comment: Thanks Itisravi. Yea, Its actually a physical layer communication protocol. So the protocol requires that the parity be changed at a particular stage, as well as the baud-rate. So what the client does is to change its parameters to that which it is expecting from the server after it sends its information. The issue is how that change in character occurs.

Comment: Are you handling the start and stop bits of 8N1 correctly?  It is easy to get shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parity and number of bits transmitted are controlled by the configuration of the UART (Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter) device in each piece of equipment.  This component converts the data written to it in (usually) byte parallel format to the data bitstream that is sent serially between the client and server (in your example).

To transmit in 7E1 the UART is configured to ignore the MSB and then to add the parity bit as the last bit of data transmitted giving 8 transmitted data bits.  In 8N1 the UART transmits the 8 data bits.  By convention the data is transmitted LSB first.

Looking at your data I would suspect that where you have written **B** you really mean **8** (this would fit with the data transmission modes specified).

When transmitting the data over a 7E1 link then the 8 bits transmitted for your data will be

```
Data   Parity Transmitted byte
 06      0       0x06
 02      1       0x82
 05      0       0x05
 02      1       0x82
 0D      1       0x8D
 0A      0       0x0A
```

Are the three middle bytes ASCII representations of the values that you have declared in your question  (2 ->0x32, 5->0x35 )?  If this is the case than the data received will match the data transmitted with the addition of a parity bit.

```
Data   Parity Transmitted byte
 06      0       0x06
 32      1       0xB2
 35      0       0x35
 32      1       0xB2
 0D      1       0x8D
 0A      0       0x0A
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is there a mismatch between the protocol of the client and that of the server?  That makes no sense.  By the way parity is a ancient relic hardly used anymore today.

However, note that 8N1 is a superset of 7E1.  In the 7E1 (7 data bits, even parity, 1 stop bit) protocol, the parity bit is dictated by the other 7 bits.  You can really only send 7 bits of information each character.  In the 8N1 (8 data bits, no parity bit, 1 stop bit) protocol, the sender controls all 8 bits.  In that case, the sender could chose emulate 7E1 in software by filling in the parity bit apporpriately.

Answer (score 1):

Seven-bit modes with parity have the same framing as 8-bit modes with no parity; the only question is what happens with the eighth bit (it's worth noting, btw, that some UARTs support 7-bit modes only with parity, and 8-bit modes only without, since the fundamental hardware is designed for 8 data bits).  Devices that send 8-bit data have to do "something" with the eighth-bit on transmission--they can set it, clear it, or make it depend upon the parity of the remaining seven bits, but something has to go out the wire during that bit time.  On the other hand, there's nothing that says devices have to do anything with all the bits of data they receive.  Many devices will simply ignore the MSB of incoming data.  Others will try to use it to infer whether they should do anything with the top bit of data they return.

A modem using Hayes® commands will generally look for consecutive "AT" characters to determine the baud rate and parity settings to use with transmission.  The "A" is chosen because it starts with "1010" on the line (including the previous idle time), which provides one-bit-wide high and low intervals.  The five consecutive zeroes cannot appear in any valid data that is sent at twice the data rate or higher.  The "T" should have its parity bit in the opposite state from the "A" if parity is used.  Once the modem has received the "AT", it ignores the parity bits on further incoming bytes, but makes its own outgoing transmission match the "AT" characters it received.

Answer (score 0):

Do you implement the mode E of IEC62056-21 named HDLC/DLMS?

Entering sequence is 06 B2 xx B2 8D 0A.

The xx for requested baudrates:

300: 30

600: B1

1200: B2

2400: 33

4800: B4

9600: 35

19200: 36

38400: B7

57600: B8

115200: 39

Be prepared for whatever might happen! Current standard (11th) is incompatible with previous versions (for example 2nd). Meaning of a few codes was changed and the standard data can have different meaning from meter to meter. For example 1-1:1.36.0*xx - xx = billing period according to 1st-9th version and multiple threshold according to 11th. 
Additionally the 62056-21 defines the baudrate of opening sequence as 300. The DLMS defines different. See IEC local port setup class. The default_baud shall be always enum(0) and the field shall not exist.

Part of meters don't need to enter by 62056-21 mode. Additionally part of meters do not support it.

The truth: the DLMS is no a true standard.It is quasi-standard. Like english language: Chinese people speak english. Slovak people speak english. Slovak can't understand Chinese and Chinese can't understand Slovak ...via english language...

We need more standards to be happy. More languages.